# How to make all fields look the same in Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I made a contact form using Contact Form 7 and now I have an issue with one different field in Contact Form 7.
Phone field appears completely different than other fields. Any idea how to fix it? Here's the contact form: http://www.alliancemetalsusa.com/contact-us/

Thank you,
M.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is some css missing for input[type="tel"]

A quickfix would be to add this to your CSS:

```
form.wpcf7-form input[type="tel"] {
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 9px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No problem! Would be happy if you marked my answer as correct :)

Comment: Would like to, but Stackexchange is so stupid, it says:"Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." 
So, I hope it really is recorded :) Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, no worries :) Thanks!